# Scala difference between (1 to 4).toSet and (1 to 4).to[scala.collection.immutable.Set]?

Tags: scala, collections

Scala difference between `(1 to 4).to[scala.collection.immutable.Set]` and `(1 to 4).toSet`?

```
scala> (1 to 4).toSet
res37: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> (1 to 4).to[scala.collection.immutable.Set]
res38: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> (1 to 4).to[Set]
res39: Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> Set(1 to 4:_*)
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `toSet`:

```
def toSet[B >: A]: immutable.Set[B] = to[immutable.Set].asInstanceOf[immutable.Set[B]]
```

you can see it's just an alias to `to[]`. So it's the same.
Note that from Scala 2.13 and up, it's `to(Set)`. See [doc](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/Iterable.html#to%5BC1%5D(factory:scala.collection.Factory%5BA,C1%5D):C1) and [release note](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0#Additional%20collections%20changes)

Comment: Where is 'def toSet[B >: A]: immutable.Set[B] = to[i...' from?

Comment: `scala.collection.Iterable`

Answer (score 1):

They should all be the same, `Set` is just an alias like so

```
type Set[A] = immutable.Set[A]
```